# 'Camera' vs 'Stanza'

Tags: word-choice

I read both *stanza* and *camera* being used to translate a *room*. Is it there a difference between them? Could you give an example of a context where they might be applied?

Answer (score 11):

Stanza is more general, and indicates any internal space of a building separated by walls (and doors). I would say that it is a more accurate translation of room, when room is intended in the general sense (e.g. not I went into my room).

Camera is used more in reference to bedroom, even though one can in general call a camera any room that is not just a passage (like a corridor).

Questo appartamento è composto da sei stanze: ingresso, cucina, salotto, bagno e due camere.

This flat comprises six rooms: entrance, kitchen, living room, bathroom and two bedrooms.

Notice that camere stands for bedrooms, one does not need to say "camere da letto" to be understood.

Comment: When I say _va in camera tua_, I don't necessarily mean the bedroom. If I were to speak to my 10 years old son, who has a bedroom, and another room, _camera_ would mean the room that is not the bedroom.

Answer (score 10):

**Camera** is mainly a "habitation unit in a house or apartment" (*["Ambiente abitativo in una casa, in un appartamento"](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/C/camera_1.shtml)*), and, while it refers in common cases to *"camera da letto"* (bedroom), it can also refer to *"camera da pranzo"* (dinner room).

It is also used in other acceptions, though.

- *Camera operatoria* (Operating theater)
- *Camera dei deputati* (House of deputies)

In all cases it is similar to "room", but with a more "elegant", "expensive" or "posh" undertone (*cf. eng. "Chamber", fr. "Chambre"*)

**Stanza** refers to any enclosed environment in a building (*["Ognuno degli ambienti interni di un edificio"](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/stanza.shtml)*). It can refer to any room in a building and in the case of habitation units it is used either as an alternative for *camera* or for other rooms for which *camera* is not normally adequate, entrance hall (*"stanza d'ingresso"*), bathroom (*"stanza da bagno"*).

It is more general than "camera" and it avoids the "posh" accent of it, as "stanza" is a term of more "functional" origin (from the verb "stare", to stand). It is best translated to English as "room" and definitely not "chamber".

Comment: A ‘veste da camera‘ is (was) not necessarily used in the bedroom, but in all ‘private‘ rooms.

Comment: minor: "operating room" is much more common than "operating theater" in English. Google results confirm it.